# Dynamic Height in a Static Table with Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, static, storyboard, height

I created a static table in storyboard and would like to enable automatic table heights.

```
class DemoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var : UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    myTextLabel.sizeToFit()
    myTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    myTextLabel.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


}
```

The constraints of the label are pinned to the cell-borders.
Pretty much the same code is working with a dynamic table.

Does anybody know how to enable auto seizing for the static table?

**Edit**
Here's the link to a GitHub-Repo:
https://github.com/pascalherrmann/Swift-Dynamic-Sized-Tables
It contains the code for a working auto-sizing dynamic table and a non-working static table.

**Edit 2**
Ok, after hours of trying I finally found the solution: it has to be

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

So remember to use the override-Attribute and use the function heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath instead of heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, if you have the same problem :)

Comment: I don't think it's something to with static table. Dynamic cells should work with both. Make sure your auto layout constraints are placed correctly! It seems like an auto layout issue.

Comment: thanks, Yalcin, for your comment! Unfortunately, I still can't figure out how it works. I've added a the source code in a GitHub Repo - it would be cool if you could check it out :) https://github.com/pascalherrmann/Swift-Dynamic-Sized-Tables